# How to fix the gas limit using asset-erc20 precompile

Tags: evm, frontier, pallet-asset

When I transfer ERC in EVM with the classic method of deployed contract it set the gas limit correctly, however when I want to transfer using the precompile ( moonbeam one ) asset-erc20 ( from metamask too ) I have an OutOfGas log in substrate and the transfer fail. It seems to use the same gas limit than "classic erc20", if I increase manually the gas limit it works. How can I make it dynamic so it adjust the gas limit correctly ?